# VBA Loop not sending data to word in a consistent way

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word, copy, paste

I have the below code that goes through a simple spreadsheet for now and paste the organisation,
one table a single cell value and a chart into a word template. The code runs and produces both a word and pdf version correctly. But what I see is that the table is on occasion ended up where the organisation should be and the chart is being repeated in the document. Each output of the loop seems to vary and I can't work out if the information is not being cleared from the clipboard before it gets pasted. Do I need to run the sections into sub sections or something?

Appreciate the help.

```
    Sub CreateBasicWordReport()
   Dim WdApp As Word.Application
   Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
   Dim SaveName As String
   Dim FileExt As String
   Dim LstObj1 As ListObject
   Dim MaxValue As Integer
   Dim FilterValue As Integer
   Dim Organisation As String
   Dim Rng As Range
   Dim WS As Worksheet
   
   Set LstObj1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
   
   MaxValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(LstObj1.ListColumns(1).Range)
    
   FilterValue = MaxValue
    
   Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Do Until FilterValue = 0
   
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
      Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet1")).Name = "Static"
      Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    
      'moved outside of loop
      ' Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   
      With WdApp
         .Visible = True
         .Activate
         'create new document and assign to object variable
         Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add("C:\Users\david\Documents\Custom Office Templates\Template2.dotx")
      'now mostly finished with WdApp as from here wdDoc is used
      End With
      ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterValue
      Range("F11").Select
              
      Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
    
      '         .Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="TableLocation"
      '         .Selection.Paste
      wdDoc.Bookmarks("TableLocation").Range.Paste
    
      For Each Row In Range("Table1[#All]").Rows
         If Row.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            If Rng Is Nothing Then Set Rng = Row
            Set Rng = Union(Row, Rng)
         End If
      Next Row
      Set WS = Sheets("Static")
      Rng.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1")

      '      Sheets("Static").Select
      '      Sheets("Static").Activate
      Organisation = WS.Range("D2").Value
    
      '      Sheets("Static").Select
      '      Range("D2").Copy
      WS.Range("D2").Copy
      
      '         .Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="Organisation"
      '         .Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
      wdDoc.Bookmarks("Organisation").Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
      '      Sheets("Static").Select
      '      Range("F2").Copy
      WS.Range("F2").Copy
      
    
      '         .Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="MalePatients"
      '         .Selection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
      wdDoc.Bookmarks("MalePatients").Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
         
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
      Chart2.ChartArea.Copy
    
      '         .Selection.GoTo what:=-1, Name:="ChartLocation"
      '         .Selection.Paste
      wdDoc.Bookmarks("ChartLocation").Range.Paste
    
      If WdApp.Version <= 11 Then
         FileExt = ".doc"
      Else
         FileExt = ".docx"
      End If
    
      SaveName = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Report for " & _
         Organisation & " " & _
         Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & FileExt
        
      If WdApp.Version <= 12 Then
         ' .ActiveDocument.SaveAs SaveName
         wdDoc.SaveAs SaveName
      Else
         ' .ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 SaveName
         wdDoc.SaveAs2 SaveName
      End If
    
      SaveNamePDF = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Report " & _
         Organisation & " " & _
         Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss") & ".pdf"

      wdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
         OutputFileName:=SaveNamePDF, _
         ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF _
    
         wdDoc.Close
    
         FilterValue = FilterValue - 1
         Sheets("Static").Delete
         
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      
   Loop

   WdApp.Quit
    
   Set WdApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may or may not want to take this as an answer to your question, but here are some ways you can improve your code so as to gain better control over how it operates. It is not a "solution" in the sense of a completed, correctly working code module, but if you adopt this advice it should enable you to solve the issue yourself (along with many other issues you might otherwise encounter in the future).

(1) Avoid using `Copy` and `Paste`. As you correctly note, those put you at the mercy of the Windows clipboard. Instead, assign the source object or value to a variable, then insert the contents of the variable at the destination. For instance:

```
Organisation = WS.Range("D2").Value
wdDoc.Bookmarks("Organisation").Range.Text = Organisation
```

Now you are able to control what is inserted at the destination point. Among other things, you can reset the variable at the end of each loop, so that there is no risk of repeatedly inserting an object or value that may be carried over from one loop cycle to the next.

(2) Use `With ... End With` to explicitly specify the parents of your objects. That way you don't risk accidentally referencing a different object than you expected. For instance, in this excerpt from your code ...

```
With WdApp
    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add("C:\Users\david\Documents\Custom Office Templates\Template2.dotx")
End With

Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
```

... the range copied in the last line may not be what you expect. If the active object at the moment is your newly minted Word doc, the `Range` object may be interpreted as some range in the document, rather than the spreadsheet range you wanted to copy.

To stay in control, use `With` consistently:

```
With WdApp
    Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add("C:\Users\david\Documents\Custom Office Templates\Template2.dotx")
End With

With MyWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet")
    Set MyTableRange = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
End With
```

That's just a couple of pointers, but these are basic good coding practices that you should adopt. I think they will help you resolve the issues with your code.

Comment: You are incorrect in your second point. Because the code is hosted in Excel `Range` will always be interpreted as being an Excel range. The only time confusion arises is if you declare a variable, e.g. `Dim WdRange as Range` instead of `Dim WdRange as Word.Range`

Comment: ... such as in the declaration `Dim Rng As Range` right here in OP's question. Your comment boils down to the idea that OP will be fine to go on relying on implicit references as long as the variable declaration is fixed. In my opinion that is very unhelpful advice (not to me, but to the new programmer who posted this question).

Comment: Everyone relies on implicit references in their code, even you. Every time you declare a variable `As String` or `As Long`, or use a function such as `Left`, `Split`, or `Trim`, you rely on an implicit reference to the VBA library. Even your code example includes two implicit references. To avoid them `xlDown` and `xlToRight` would have to be written as `Excel.xlDown` and `Excel.xlToRight`.

Comment: Where you are incorrect in your second point is stating that `Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy` could be interpreted as belonging to Word. That couldn't happen. However, if a different sheet in the workbook was activated the range could then be taken from the wrong sheet. I agree that it is good practice to be specific about the workbook/worksheet that is being referred to. You simply used the wrong conclusion to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 0):

The issues you are seeing are likely being caused by using the clipboard. There can be a delay when copying and pasting larger items, e.g. tables of data, charts.

When you use the clipboard you are passing some control over to the OS. VBA includes a function, `DoEvents` that passes control to the operating system. Control is then returned after the operating system has finished processing the events in its queue. By adding this after each copy/paste it should allow things to catch up.

You can also slightly reduce your use of the clipboard by setting the values for 'Organisation' and 'Male Patients' directly.

```
Sub CreateBasicWordReport()
   Dim WdApp As Word.Application
   Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
   Dim SaveName As String
   Dim FileExt As String
   Dim LstObj1 As ListObject
   Dim MaxValue As Integer
   Dim FilterValue As Integer
   Dim Organisation As String
   Dim Rng As Range
   Dim WS As Worksheet
   
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Set LstObj1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
   
   MaxValue = WorksheetFunction.Max(LstObj1.ListColumns(1).Range)
    
   FilterValue = MaxValue
    
   Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Do Until FilterValue = 0
    
      Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Sheet1")).Name = "Static"
      Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   
      With WdApp
         .Visible = True
         .Activate
         'create new document and assign to object variable
         Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add("C:\Users\david\Documents\Custom Office Templates\IBD Registry Quarterly Report Template2.dotx")
         'now mostly finished with WdApp as from here wdDoc is used
      End With
      
      ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterValue
      Range("F11").Select
              
      Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy
    
      wdDoc.Bookmarks("TableLocation").Range.Paste
      DoEvents
      
      For Each Row In Range("Table1[#All]").Rows
         If Row.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            If Rng Is Nothing Then Set Rng = Row
            Set Rng = Union(Row, Rng)
         End If
      Next Row
      Set WS = Sheets("Static")
      Rng.Copy Destination:=WS.Range("A1")
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      DoEvents

      Organisation = WS.Range("D2").Value
      wdDoc.Bookmarks("Organisation").Range.Text = Organisation
    
      wdDoc.Bookmarks("MalePatients").Range.Text = WS.Range("F2").Text
    
      Chart2.ChartArea.Copy
      wdDoc.Bookmarks("ChartLocation").Range.Paste
      DoEvents
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
      If CLng(WdApp.Version) <= 11 Then
         FileExt = ".doc"
      Else
         FileExt = ".docx"
      End If
    
      SaveName = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\IBD Registry Quarterly Report for " & _
         Organisation & " " & _
         Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss")
      SaveNamePDF = SaveName & ".pdf"
      SaveName = SaveName & FileExt
      
      If CLng(WdApp.Version) <= 12 Then
         wdDoc.SaveAs SaveName
      Else
         wdDoc.SaveAs2 SaveName
      End If
    
      wdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat _
         OutputFileName:=SaveNamePDF, _
         ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF _

         wdDoc.Close

         FilterValue = FilterValue - 1
         
         Sheets("Static").Delete
         
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      
   Loop

   WdApp.Quit
    
   Set WdApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```